# How to easiest rename|apply naming style for all member in my class|namespace

Tags: resharper

We have started using Resharper 4.5 and the naming style functionality that comes with it. 
There is some tedious work applying the naming styles.

What I would whould like is to apply my naming styles or part of it as a part of my Code cleanup profile.

Any1 know how to do it, or atleast a less tedious job than spaming  + PgDown,  +  + ?

Answer (score 1):

It does not worth the while for legacy code. I suggest you start using new style for new code and slowly migrate existing code.

Comment: It's a part of the active code base, therefore I will update the names and keep the code alive. I do not want my code to rot.;)

Answer (score 0):

Macros would be my suggestion, you should be able to handle this with macros.

Comment: I did give it a try. Did not do the trick. Could be the fact that I'm new to macros that is the reason. 
I did record the operation some times. Tried to play the macro without success.
So I'm still looking. :)

Answer (score 0):

VisualAssist might help you significantly in renaming/refactoring (trial-version can be downloaded from http://www.wholetomato.com). 
But it is not something to enforce your coding guidelines, though.